# Wordpress: Cannot set ACF repeater field of a post after wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm now using *WordPress Advanced Custom Fields* Plugin: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

And I set a repeater field `rows` on my custom *post_type* `sales_order`:

Then, now insert a post using script:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_name' => $slug,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_type' => 'sales_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
));
```

But when I do:

```
update_field('rows', array(), $post_id);
```

It has no effect.

But if I manually save the post in the admin panel first, then call the `update_field` method, it works.

---

So, I tried to spy the `wp_postmeta` database table, I found that if I call `wp_insert_post` using script, that post don't generate the meta

```
| meta_key | meta_value          |
|----------|---------------------|
| _rows    | field_568e7aeb22714 |
```

correctly.

But I have to do the import workflow using pure script, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a solution according the source.

---

## Reason:

Why the below action fails?

```
update_field('rows', array(), $post_id);
```

Now we're using the **field name**, not the **field key**.

In this case, ACF would do the follows:

1. Try to find the current post meta which has a `meta_key`: `_rows`, which prepend an under-slash before the **field name**.
2. After that, get that `meta_value`, it should be a **field key** which has a form like `field_XXXXXXX`
3. Update the field with the founded **field_key**.

Now we know, if we do `wp_insert_post` in such a way, the `_rows` meta did not generate the correct `meta_value`.

So if we update the post in the admin panel, the **field key** was then submitted and generating the correct `meta_value`.

> **Conclusion:** Only *THAT* meta value matters.

---

## Solution:

So, in fact, the only things we should do more is to set that meta_values defined in the ACF field set bound to the specified `post_type`.

The below routine worked that around:

```
// The current post_type to search
$post_type = 'sales_order';

$post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_name' => $slug,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
));

foreach (get_posts(array('post_type' => 'acf', 'posts_per_page' => -1)) as $acf) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($acf->ID);
    $rule = unserialize($meta['rule'][0]);
    if($rule['param'] == 'post_type' &&
        $rule['operator'] == '==' &&
        $rule['value'] == $post_type) {
        foreach($meta as $key => $field) {
            if(substr($key, 0, 6) == 'field_') {
                $field = unserialize($field[0]);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$field['name'], $key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, we loop through all defined ACF posts, and check for the `rule` meta, to confirm if it was bounded on the specified `post_type`.

If so, loop all that ACF meta starts with `field_`, and set the meta on the current post.

All done.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `field_name` but `update_field` requires `field_key` as the documentation says [update_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/)

Consider this example

```
update_field('field_568e7aeb22714', array(), $post_id);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution is not good enough: 1. field name is also allowed. 2. How do I know the key `field_568e7aeb22714`? Hard coding it in my code must be a nightmare in the future!

Comment: Please consider their article  1. `You can and should use the $field_key 100% of the time.` 2. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#finding-the%20field%20key

Comment: Well I am not good with this plugin because I use WordPress meta boxes and update_post_meta :)

Comment: Well it does the job but what about the load to just run an update query you are pulling everything and looping though that?

Comment: There won't be a lot of ACF post defined, and if the performance do matters, we can cache the load.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0; //for metakey
$j=0; //files Count

foreach($files as $fileid){
    $j++;
    $meta_key = 'files_'.$i.'_file';
    //"files" repeater main name and "file" subname ;
    update_post_meta($post_id,$meta_key,$fileid);
    $i++;

}
update_post_meta($post_id,'files',$j);
```